# Problemas con los acentos y "ñ" al generar csv

Tags: php, csv

estoy generando un CSV con PHP simplemente escribiendo los literales en la pagina html y separándolos con ";" y forzando a que genere el .csv y lo descargue. El código seria algo así:

```
<?php

//nombre del fichero que se va a descargar desde el navegador
$filename= "informe_firma_digital.csv";

//Headers para decir que es un archivo csv y forzar a que el navegador lo descargue
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

//linea del csv
echo "Ramón; España; Calle Balón; Alcorcón; 28054".PHP_EOL;

?>
```

El problema es que al generarse el .csv las tildes y "ñ" aparecen con caracteres "raros" ¿como solucionarlo? gracias!!

Comment: Creo que tu problema está antes, en la generación del archivo informe_firma_digital.csv, verifica las propiedades del archivo que sea UTF-8

Comment: Hola, Prueba añadiendo `utf8_encode()` entonces te quedaría así `echo utf8_encode("Ramón; España; Calle Balón; Alcorcón; 28054").PHP_EOL;`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que añadir el `encoding`

```
<?php

//nombre del fichero que se va a descargar desde el navegador
$filename= "informe_firma_digital.csv";

//Headers para decir que es un archivo csv y forzar a que el navegador lo descargue

header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');

//linea del csv
echo "Ramón; España; Calle Balón; Alcorcón; 28054".PHP_EOL;

?>
```